# Upload big files asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, telerik

I have an ASP.NET WebForms application.

In my page I have the upload file option. 
I worked with telerik:RadAsyncUpload

Now some browser does not work and I got many bugs from users that the uploader does not work for them.

I look for upload option that work with ASP.NET WebForms application, and the user can upload big files (like 500 MB +-)

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET by default allows the maximum file size upload to be 4 MB. If you want to support larger files then you need to set the maxRequestLength property in your web.config file to a larger value
(Reference: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

Alternatively, you can use the ChunkSize property of RadAsyncUpload to first split the file into smaller chunks and upload them separately as shown in this [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/large-file-uploads/defaultcs.aspx)